# An odd "XML parsing failed" still after using jstl c:out

Tags: xml, jstl

The jstl c:out tag can escape xml characters. However, I still got the "XML parsing failed" as followed:

```
XML parsing failed
XML parsing failed: syntax error (Line: 34, Character: 3)

Error:
invalid character

Specification:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char

31:
32: <a href="someUrl">userA</a>
33: Says:
34: \11\08\10\10\10\11
35: (13:47)
36:
37:<br/>
```

Now I'm confused by the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\11 (=`U+000B`) is [not a valid character in an XML 1.0 document](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets).

This is probably the result of a broken encoding. Make sure you're using UTF-8, and investigate where that strange character comes from.